# How to design Context Free Grammar for the language $L=\{0^{i}1^{j}0^{j}1^{i} | i,j\ge0\}$?

Tags: automata

I have tried following.

S -> AB

A -> 0A1|01

B -> 0B1|01

Are there better way to do it? Thanks

Comment: That seems to generate $\{0^{i}1^{i}0^{j}1^{j} | i,j\ge1\}$ rather than $L$ (e.g. how would you generate $011001$?)

Comment: @BrianMoehring $i,j\ge 1$

Comment: @Hagen Thanks.  I was more interested in the order of the indices than whether it worked when either $i,j$ is zero, but you're right. (Fixed it in time)

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks. I understood your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your grammar allows $S\to AB\to 01B\to 010B1\to 010011\notin L$, and it does not allow $S\to \epsilon$, for example.
How about
$$ S\to 0S1\mid A,\qquad A\to 1A0\mid \epsilon$$
?

Comment: Thanks, I understood this.